# php-bcmatch installation on php7 running amzon linux os

Tags: php, linux, php-7

I am trying to install php-bcmath on amazon os

```
sudo yum install php-bcmath
```

But i got the following error

```
Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Also i have tried with  `sudo yum install php-bcmath --skip-broken` but the same error will be returned

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have installed php70 in your system and default php version provided by os is php 5.3
Try this to install bcmath one of below command will work.

```
sudo yum install php70-php-bcmath
```

or

```
sudo yum install php70-bcmath
```

Hopen this will help.